# Select multiple records in gsp table using checkboxes?

Tags: grails

I'm planning to do this with items in my gsp table and am wondering if there's any 'grail-y' way to do this that doesn't require javascript to iterate through the table's rows to collect a list of id's for selected rows (where checkbox[row] = 'true') to send back to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use data binding:

### HTML

```
<g:each var="item" in="${items}">
    <input name="item" value="${item.id}" type="checkbox"/>
</g:each>
```

### Controller

```
def readItems(){
    def items = params.list("item") // You must to use list to retrieve params
    log.info "There are ${items.size()} item(s) selected"
}
```

Comment: Im not getting checkbox using above code of gsp.Let me explain you thing I wanna do.I have checkbox in one column if selected value of next column need to be send to controller.

Comment: How many values you need send to controller? You can associate an array of value to chackbox "value" attribute. Remember, checkbox value attribute is the key to send values to controller.